# Using ILogger in parallel

Tags: async-await, .net-5, parallel.foreach, ilogger

In the following code, the program terminates before the log has been fully flushed:

```cs
    class Program
    {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
        var count = -1;
        var tasks = new ConcurrentBag<Task>();

        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddLogging(configure => configure.AddConsole());
        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        var logger = serviceProvider.GetService<ILogger<Program>>();
        if (logger is null)
          throw new NullReferenceException();

        Parallel.ForEach(Enumerable.Range(0, 1000), i =>
        {
          tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => logger.LogInformation(Interlocked.Increment(ref count).ToString())));
          //tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine(Interlocked.Increment(ref count).ToString())));
        });

        Task.WhenAll(tasks).Wait();
      }
    }
```

Even though 1.000 log statements should be printed, only the following is flushed:

```
info: Net5.Program[0]
      6
info: Net5.Program[0]
      2
info: Net5.Program[0]
      5
info: Net5.Program[0]
      1
info: Net5.Program[0]
      7
info: Net5.Program[0]
      4
info: Net5.Program[0]
      3
info: Net5.Program[0]
      0
info: Net5.Program[0]
      8
info: Net5.Program[0]
      10

C:\Users\MyName\source\repos\ConsoleApp\Net5\bin\Debug\net5.0\Net5.exe (process 28048) exited with code 0.
Press any key to close this window . . .
```

When using `Console.WriteLine` (commented out in the code above), however, all lines are printed, which leads be to suspect that the console logger is asynchronous behind the scenes.

How can I ensure that all log statements are awaited without resorting to a manual delay?

**Edit:**

I settled on the following code, which did the trick:

```cs
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    var count = -1;

    var services = new ServiceCollection();
    services.AddLogging(configure => configure.AddConsole());
    using var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    var logger = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();

    var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 50000)
      .AsParallel()
      .Select(_ => Task.Run(() => logger.LogInformation(Interlocked.Increment(ref count).ToString())));

    Task.WhenAll(tasks).Wait();
  }
}
```

Key differences:

- Service Provider is disposed, which fixed the log flushing issue.
- Get ILogger instance by using `GetRequiredService` to avoid having to null check.
- Use `Enumerable.Range(...).AsParallel.Select(...)` instead of `Parallel.ForEach` to stick with Tasks all the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dispose of the service provider, it will dispose of all singleton services and that will flush the logger.

There's also no need to use `Parallel.ForEach`. In fact, using `Parallel.ForEach` with `async``await` is a code smell. It's almost always wrong.

And, since you tagged the question `.NET 5.0`, you can change your code to:

```cs
class Program
{
    static async Task Main()
    {
        var count = -1;
        var tasks = new ConcurrentBag<Task>();

        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddLogging(configure => configure.AddConsole());
        using var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        var logger = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();

        for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => logger.LogInformation(Interlocked.Increment(ref count).ToString())));
        };

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wonderful, simply putting a `using` in front of `var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();` did the trick. thank you! Also for the advice on the null check.

Regarding the Parallel.ForEach, the intention was to hurry up the creation of tasks, as my real scope is rather larger than this boiled-down example. I do, however, agree that (1) instead of a `foreach` variation I should have used a `for` loop in the example above, and (2) that sticking with tasks would be the better option.

I'll go with `Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).AsParallel.Select`, see updated question if curious.

Comment: What benefits do you expect parallelizing the invocation of `Task.Run`? Use https://benchmarkdotnet.org/ to measure the performance.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I didn't know of it, but it looks very useful! I expected and experienced a vast performance improvement. For 100 tasks, the serial implementation was slightly faster, for both 10.000 and 1.000.000 tasks the parallel implementation was more than three times as fast. See test and results here: https://pastebin.com/91jLDDXb

Comment: Overall execution of the program 3x?

Comment: Yes, you can see the exact code executed and the benchmark results in the pastebin link above.